# D3.js multiple graphs from CSV or JSON call?

Tags: d3.js

I have some data in a .csv as well as JSON. The csv has 10 rows with 25 columns (I can transpose in Excel if need be). The JSON is formatted as an array of objects where each object contains the column heading and label: data as key: value pairs. 
The sum of each column (or data values in each object of the JSON will always be 100)

I would like a bar chart for each JSON object (same as each CSV column, or if transposed, row).

I've seen some guides on how to do this, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480 but it involves separating the csv and calling it for each graph.

Would appreciate any guidance on how to get a graph for each from a single call to d3.csv or d3.json.

Comment: I'm pretty new to D3 so literally have just been following tutorials and examples online. I guess I could to a loop/forEach to create a new SVG for each object in the JSON. But was looking for some documented/built-in way.

Answer (score 0):

Your json code can be converted from csv as-

```
let dataset = d3.layout.stack()(['value1', 'value2', 
'value3'].map((value) => {
  return data.map((d: any) => {
    return { x: obj[d.xAxis], y: d.value };
  });
}));

let x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map((d) => { return d.x; }))
  .rangeBands([0, width], 1);

let y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d) => {
    return d3.max(d, (d1) => { return d1.y0 + d1.y; });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
```

For more - https://github.com/amanjain325/angular-d3-charts/blob/master/src/app/single-bar-chart/single-bar-chart.component.ts

Comment: thanks for your response but for this wouldn't I be manually inputting the data where 'value 1', 'value 2' etc. are? I don't see it reading from .csv